# 2 setTimeout function the first one clears the second one javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a problem with set and clear Timeout in javascript.
I want to set var test2 as a backup for var test
but if test works I have to delete the test2

```
var timeSec=2000;

var test = setTimeout(function() {
          clearTimeout(test2);
          jQuery('.next',curdoc)[0].click();

    }, timeSec);
var test2 = setTimeout(function() {
              // do something else
        }, timeSec+timeSec);
```

Comment: test2 timeout will never be executed.

Comment: in my case it does it is a firefox plugin. but the website where I use this plugin is buggy sometimes...

Comment: What do you mean with "if test works"? How does that translate into code? There are no checks in `var test`... so `test2` will never execute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing `test` does is clearing the `test2` timeout. This will happen after `timeSec`. `test2` will never get executed because it will run after `timeSec * 2` but gets cleared half time in.
You should clear `test2` only after successful execution of whatever `test` is going to do.

```
var timeSec=2000;

var test = setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.next',curdoc)[0].click();
      if(successful()) {
          clearTimeout(test2);
      }
}, timeSec);
var test2 = setTimeout(function() {
          // do something else
}, timeSec+timeSec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)?.

```
var test = setTimeout(function() {
          try {
            jQuery('.next',curdoc)[0].click();
          }
          catch(err) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              alert('fallback');
            }, timeSec+timeSec);
          }
    }, timeSec);
```